# Rotate values of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, rotation

Input :-    `{34: 'apple', 65: 'ball', 32: 'cat', 78: 'dog'}`

Output :-   `{34: 'dog', 65: 'apple', 32: 'ball', 78: 'cat'}`

I have come up with the following approach but is there any faster way to perform this task?

```
def rotate_values(my_dict):
    keys_list = list(my_dict.keys())
    values_list = list(my_dict.values())
    values_list.insert(0, values_list.pop())
    my_dict = dict(zip(keys_list, values_list))
    return my_dict
```

Comment: I think your solution is pretty good.

Comment: The only improvement I can see is to not create keys_list. Use my_dict.keys() directly.

Comment: Generally dictionaries aren't ordered (although in newer versions of python, iterating through a dict has a deterministic order). So the idea of a rotation isn't necessarily clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is linear, which you cannot improve as you have to rebind each key. You do not, however, have to transform the keys to a list (`zip` will work with any iterable), and you should use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for the rotation as it supports `O(1)` operations on both ends and thus constant time rotation:

```
from collections import deque

def rotate_values(my_dict):
    # no need to cast the keys to list
    values_deque = deque(my_dict.values())
    values_deque.rotate(1)
    return dict(zip(my_dict.keys(), values_deque))
```

Keep in mind that this process is not deterministic as `dicts` are unordered. Repeating it `len(my_dict)` times will not necessarily produce the original.

Comment: [Isn't dict ordering guaranteed in 3.7](https://github.com/naftaliharris/tauthon/issues/86). Also, is `.rotate(1)` [faster](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) than `.append(...popleft()`?

Comment: @modesitt Good point, didn't even know the `rotate` method. The guarantee you talk about is not a feature of the programming language Python 3.7, but merely a side effect of details of the most common implementation. Code should not rely on it.

Comment: @schwobaseggl The guarantee of dict order is an official feature of Python 3.7 and can be relied upon since that version.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack the values into the last value and the rest, and then re-pack them as a sequence with last value in the front:

```
def rotate_values(my_dict):
    if not my_dict:
        return {}
    *rest, last = my_dict.values()
    return dict(zip(my_dict, (last, *rest)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take values from `my_dict` and create a list. As you wander items of `my_dict`, you can assign values from `values` list to `my_dict` items's values.

```
my_dict = {34: 'apple', 65: 'ball', 32: 'cat', 78: 'dog'}

values = list(my_dict.values())
i = len(values)-1
for item in my_dict:
    my_dict[item] = values[i]
    i -= 1

print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

this my version:

```
ks = list(d1.keys()) # [34, 65, 32, 78]

d2 = [d1[x] for x in d1.keys()][::-1] # ['dog', 'cat', 'ball', 'apple']

result = {x[0]:x[1] for x in list(zip(ks,d2))} #  {34: 'dog', 65: 'cat', 32: 'ball', 78: 'apple'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import deque


def rotate(d, n=1):
    """
    @param d: input python dictionary
    @param n: number of times to rotate it; default:1

    @return do: output dict rotated n times
    ex: d = {34: 'apple', 65: 'ball', 32: 'cat', 78: 'dog'}
        rotate(d, 1) -> {34: 'dog', 65: 'apple', 32: 'ball', 78: 'cat'}
    """

    # Get the values of the dict and put them into a deque collection that contains a rotate method
    do = deque(d.values())
    do.rotate(n)  # rotate the values by n
    do = dict(zip(d.keys(), do))  # recombine the keys and values

    return do
```

**Demo:**

```
In [1]: d = {34: 'apple', 65: 'ball', 32: 'cat', 78: 'dog'}

In [2]: rotate(d)
Out[2]: {34: 'dog', 65: 'apple', 32: 'ball', 78: 'cat'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use iterators to do the cycling:

```
from itertools import chain

def rotate_values(my_dict):
    keys = iter(my_dict.keys())
    keys = chain(keys, [next(keys)])
    return dict(zip(keys, my_dict.values()))
```

which does the right thing for me, giving:

```
{65: 'apple', 32: 'ball', 78: 'cat', 34: 'dog'}
```

as stated elsewhere dictionaries aren't ordered, so the utility of this code is debatable, but thought it would be interesting to show another way of solving this

Comment: That rotates in the opposite direction from what the OP asks for.

Comment: @blhsing I don't think so, the OP asked for a dictionary where `65: 'apple'`

Comment: You're right, as long as the dict order is not important, although I suspect that the very requirement of a "rotation" implies that the dict order is important.

Comment: @blhsing that was what my "dictionaries aren't ordered" comment was about!