# circular changing of key values in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict :

```
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

Is there any python API which allows getting the bellow result

```
API(d)... = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 0}

API(d)... = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}

API(d)... = {'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate values of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366635/rotate-values-of-a-dictionary)

Comment: Note that unless you're python3.7+, your dictionnary has no strict ordering, so the actual order of keys/values in your dictionnary will vary

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it simply without taking much help from any non-standard library, like :

```
def rotate(d):
    keys = d.keys()
    values = list(d.values())
    values = values[1:] + values[:1]
    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    return d


d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
d = rotate(d)
print(d)
d = rotate(d)
print(d)
d = rotate(d)
print(d)
d = rotate(d)
print(d)
```

Output :

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 0}
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}
{'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this. Write a function which rotates the list in the clock-wise direction.

```
def API(d):
    val=list(d.values())
    val.append(val.pop(0))
    return dict(zip(d,val))

d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
d= API(d)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 0}
d= API(d)
# {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}
d= API(d)
# {'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```